# Как правильно отвечать?

Tags: обсуждение

Уже дважды от опытных участников получил замечание типа: "Это не ответ, используйте комментарий".
Не понимаю, почему не ответ, поясните, пожалуйста, на примере ниже.

**Пример:** дан текст функции с вопросом: "Почему в ругается Invalid syntax на n-ой аргументе, когда даю значение в  def SampleMean(table, 10, 20)?"

**Мой ответ:** "Если всё так и написано, то прямо в def ставить 10 и 20 нельзя. Это же функция. Добавьте main, вызывайте функцию оттуда." Что в нём не так, он же отвечает на вопрос "почему ругается" и даже говорит, что сделать? И рекомендации Справки (ниже) соответствует, разве что совсем уж мелкие детали я не стал приводить (не писать же ещё и текст main в одну строку - тоже на замечание могу нарваться за "медвежью услугу сообществу").

**Доп.информация:**
*Справка говорит:* "Внимательно прочитайте вопрос, уясните, в чем заключается его суть. Перед написанием ответа подумайте, чем он будет полезен. Не стоит отвечать просто «не делай этого», следует добавить «попробуй вместо этого сделать следующее» — предложите достойную альтернативу. Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получил тем временем ответ от одного из опытных участников:
"Ответ - это развернутая рекомендация по решению вопроса, а не попытка, основанная на догадках. Мы с вами точно не знаем, помогут ли наши советы автору вопроса."

Я-то был точно уверен:-), но опытному участнику виднее.
Так что считаю вопрос отвеченным.

Comment: Не всем опытным (многореповым) участникам и не во всем надо доверять. А вот самому проверять свои ответы **на компе** надо обязательно.